# Definition and usage of Kernel/Linux DTS file with more than one MIPI DSI Display panel

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot, display-settings, panel, device-tree

I actually need some help of defining the kernel/linux DTS file and use it together with the uboot videoargs.

In use is the 5.4.47 uboot and kernel/linux from a NXP imx8m YOCTO project.

In uboot I already can use 5 different MIPI DSI display panels and a HDMI adapter from nxp. To configure the displays type in uboot, I use the video_link environment variable. This works fine for me and can easily be extended and configured. To get this work my uboot DTS looks like this:

```
#include <dt-bindings/usb/pd.h>
#include "imx8mm.dtsi"

/ {
    model = "My own board";
    compatible = "fsl,imx8mm-evk", "fsl,imx8mm";
    
    .
    .
    .
    
    dsi_host: dsi-host {
        compatible = "samsung,sec-mipi-dsi";
        status = "okay";
    };  

    01_panel {
        compatible = "mydisplay,01_display";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_mipi_dsi_en>;
        reset-gpio = <&gpio1 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        dsi-lanes = <4>;
        video-mode = <2>;   /* 0: burst mode
                     * 1: non-burst mode with sync event
                     * 2: non-burst mode with sync pulse
                     */
        panel-width-mm = <67>;
        panel-height-mm = <121>;
        status = "okay";

        port {
            01_from_dsim: endpoint {
                remote-endpoint = <&dsim_to_01>;
            };
        };
    };

    02_panel {
        compatible = "mydisplay,02_display";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_mipi_dsi_en>;
        reset-gpio = <&gpio1 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        dsi-lanes = <4>;
        video-mode = <2>;   /* 0: burst mode
                     * 1: non-burst mode with sync event
                     * 2: non-burst mode with sync pulse
                     */
        panel-width-mm = <67>;
        panel-height-mm = <121>;
        status = "okay";

        port {
            02_from_dsim: endpoint {
                remote-endpoint = <&dsim_to_02>;
            };
        };
    };

    .
    .
    .
};

.
.
.

&mipi_dsi {
    status = "okay";

    port@1 {
        dsim_to_adv7535: endpoint {
            remote-endpoint = <&adv7535_from_dsim>;
        };
    };

    port@2 {
        dsim_to_01: endpoint {
            remote-endpoint = <&01_from_dsim>;
        };
    };

    port@3 {
        dsim_to_02: endpoint {
            remote-endpoint = <&02_from_dsim>;
        };
    };
    
    .
    .
    .
};
```

Now I want to use the same displays in kernel/linux, of course. I first tried the same DTS structure like above from uboot DTS file. I also used the following configuration of the kernel/linux DTS:

```
#include "imx8mm.dtsi"

/ {
    model = "My own board";
    compatible = "fsl,imx8mm-flunder", "fsl,imx8mm";
    reserved-memory {
        #address-cells = <2>;
        #size-cells = <2>;
        ranges;

        rpmsg_reserved: rpmsg@0xb8000000 {
            no-map;
            reg = <0 0xb8000000 0 0x400000>;
        };
    };
    
    .
    .
    .
};

.
.
.

&mipi_dsi {
  status = "okay";

    port@1 {
        dsim_to_adv7535: endpoint {
            remote-endpoint = <&adv7535_from_dsim>;
        };
    };

    panel@0 {
        compatible = "mydisplay,01_display";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        reg = <0>;
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_mipi_dsi_en>;
        reset-gpio = <&gpio1 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        dsi-lanes = <4>;
        video-mode = <2>;   /* 0: burst mode
                        * 1: non-burst mode with sync event
                        * 2: non-burst mode with sync pulse
                        */
        panel-width-mm = <62>;
        panel-height-mm = <110>;
        status = "okay";
    };

    panel@1 {
        compatible = "mydisplay,02_display";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        reg = <0>;
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_mipi_dsi_en>;
        reset-gpio = <&gpio1 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        dsi-lanes = <4>;
        video-mode = <2>;   /* 0: burst mode
                        * 1: non-burst mode with sync event
                        * 2: non-burst mode with sync pulse
                        */
        panel-width-mm = <62>;
        panel-height-mm = <110>;
        status = "okay";
    };
};

.
.
.
```

The second variant ends in the usage of the panel 0, while the kernel boots. But in both variants I was not able to tell the kernel/linux, from the uboot side, which display I want to use.

As boot- or videoargs from uboot side I tested many variants without any success.

A short example list you can see here:

```
video=imx-drm:720x1280@60
primary_display=imx-drm
video=DSI-1:dev=01,720x1280@60
video=mxcfb0:dev=ldb,01_panel,if=RGB24
video=mxcfb0:dev=mipi_dsi,01_panel,if=RGB24
video=DSI-1:dev=01_panel
video=mxcfb0:dev=mipi_dsi,720x1280M@60,if=RGB24
video=mxcfb0:dev=ldb,720x1280M@60,if=RGB24
video=DSI-1:720x1280@60
```

In my opinion the first configuration, like I use in uboot, is the correct one, but I end in the questions:

- How is the correct configuration of the kernel/linux DTS file for more than one MIPI DSI Display?
- How can I tell the Kernel while booting which display it has to use?